# Структуры, функции и массивы

Tags: c, массивы, функции

Здравствуйте! Хочу написать код, где программа с помощью функций высчитывает средний вес спортсменов заданной страны из массивы структур. Проблема заключается в том, что я не могу разобраться, как корректно прописать аргументы, хотя без функций код работает.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define N 2

using namespace std;

float ves(char, struct);


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");


    struct SPORT
    {
        char surname[10];
        char country[10];
        int year;
        float result;
        float height;
        float weight;

    }mas[N];

    int *ptr_mas = &mas;

    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Введите фамилию спортсмена"<<' '<<i+1<<endl;
        cin>>mas[i].surname;
        cout<<"Введите страну спортсмена"<<' '<<i+1<<endl;
        cin>>mas[i].country;
        cout<<"Введите год рождения спортсмена"<<' '<<i+1<<endl;
        cin>>mas[i].year;
        cout<<"Введите результат спортсмена"<<' '<<i+1<<endl;
        cin>>mas[i].result;
        cout<<"Введите рост спортсмена"<<' '<<i+1<<endl;
        cin>>mas[i].height;
        cout<<"Введите вес спортсмена"<<' '<<i+1<<endl;
        cin>>mas[i].weight;
    }
    cout<<"Фамилия\t\t";
    cout<<"Страна\t\t";
    cout<<"Год\t\t";
    cout<<"Результат\t";
    cout<<"Рост\t";
    cout<<"Вес\t"<<endl;

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cout<<mas[i].surname<<"\t\t";
        cout<<mas[i].country<<"\t\t";
        cout<<mas[i].year<<"\t\t";
        cout<<mas[i].result<<"\t\t";
        cout<<mas[i].height<<"\t";
        cout<<mas[i].weight<<"\t"<<endl;

    }

    char strana[10];
    cout<<"Назовите страну:";
    cin>>strana;

    cout<<"Средний вес по стране равен:"<<ves(char strana, struct SPORT);

    return 0;

}

 float ves(char strana, struct SPORT )
{
    int kol = 0;
    float ves1 = 0;
    int i;
    for(*ptr_mas = &mas; *ptr_mas < N; ptr_mas++)
    {
        if(!strcmp(mas[i].country, strana))
        {
            ves1 = ves1 + mas[i].weight;
            kol++;
        }

    }
    sr = ves1/kol;

    return sr;
}
```

Спасибо.

```
    float ves(char strana, struct SPORT *mas);

     float ves(char strana, struct SPORT *mas)
    {
        int kol = 0;
        float ves1 = 0;
        int i;
        float sr;

       /* for(ptr = mas ; ptr < ptr + N; ptr++)
        {
            if(!strcmp(*ptr, strana))
            {
                ves1 = ves1 + mas[i].weight;
                kol++;
            }

        }*/
        sr = ves1/kol;

        return sr;
    }

    struct SPORT
        {
            char surname[10];
            char country[10];
            int year;
            float result;
            float height;
            float weight;

        }mas[N];


        int *ptr = mas;




    int main()
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");



    char strana[10];
    cout<<"Назовите страну:";
    cin>>strana;

    //cout<<"Средний вес по стране равен:"<<ves(strana, *ptr)<<endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Область видимости структуры PORT -- функция main, так как она у Вас объявлена локально. Вынесите за пределы функции main ее объявление, а в функцию ves лучше всего передавать массив (через указатель,т.е.).

```
  float ves(char strana, struct PORT *mas, size_t sz);
```

Итерации по массиву структур :

```
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
     if (mas[i].country == strana) {
     }
  }
```

Comment: а что будет означать size_t sz?

Comment: @AndreyKompaniets размер массива

Comment: а будет ли правильно указатель сделать int *ptr = &mas?

Comment: @AndreyKompaniets имя массива уже само под собой подразумевает указатель на первый элемент массива, так что не нужно брать ссылку с помощью &

Comment: при объявлении указателя выдает: cannot convert "SPORT*" to int* in initial.

Comment: @AndreyKompaniets приведите этот кусок кода в вопросе

Comment: @AndreyKompaniets если в том куске, про который Вы спрашивали выше, то там очевидно что вы объявляете ptr с типом указатель на int, а mas у Вас типа struct SPORT

Comment: Действительно, перестал ругаться. Спасибо. А теперь, если мне надо бегать по значениям переменной в массиве структур, то как прописать это через указатель, к примеру, в структуре есть char country?

Comment: @AndreyKompaniets добавил в ответ, если Вы об этом. Или Вам нужно именно через адресную арифметику?

Comment: Скорей всего, как вы написали. Ведь если это будет в функции, оно сможет искать по структуре?

Comment: @AndreyKompaniets да, конечно, Вы ведь ее в качестве параметра туда и передаете. Если мой ответ Вам помог, отметьте его как правильный, галочкой

Comment: Видимо, из-за того, что я изначально структуру не сделал глобальной, пошел в дебри с указателями и тут утонул. Попробую еще раз сделать. Спасибо Вам.

Comment: А можно ли ли здесь Вас как-то зафрендить или чтобы контакт остался?

Comment: @AndreyKompaniets в en версии есть chat.stackoverflow.com , в русской его вроде бы нету. Можете написать мне в телеграм, номер указан в профиле

Comment: еще одно: как корректно передать фактический аргумент с указателем. на ves(strana, *ptr) и ves(strana, SPORT *ptr)  ругается

Comment: @AndreyKompaniets ves(strana, mas, 10) в моей реализации